# Android cannot connect to Pi's wlan

Tags: pi-3, wifi, pi-3b+, android

I'm running a Node server on port :3000 and want to access it from other devices using Pi's wlan0 address.

wlan0: 169.254.36.22

- Accessing from Macbook works
- Accessing from iPhone works
- Accessing from Android doesn't work (connection timeout)

eth0: 192.168.132 - Accessing from all 3 devices works good.

What could be the potential cause of this problem?

I lost every hope in Android devices. They don't support zeroconf (raspberrypi.local) out of the box, and now this weird problem.

Comment: I'm surprised anything can connect to a `169.254.x.x` address - but I guess zeroconf makes that possible - read up on what 169.254.x.x addresses are ... then give you wlan a useful IP address instead

Comment: @JaromandaX That's what confused me. I'm familiar with 169 but it was unclear why iPhone and Mac would connect and Android no

Comment: @Dino is Android connected on the same access point with the other 2 computers?

Comment: @GramThanos yes all 3 of them are on same AP

Comment: Does the answer help you? If so, please accept it by clicking the tick on its left side. This will close the question and it will not pop up again and again and ...

Comment: @Ingo It did not work for me. I guess that I am in the same situation of the original poster. Here more details: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107188/android-wont-connect-to-raspi-access-point

Answer (score 1):

The answer is already given in your question. Android does not support link-local ip addresses out of the box. It needs a DHCP server. If you are interested for details I have just verified this in [Check up - Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93662/79866). On **Checkpoint 4** you will see the access point (*RPiNet*) in the list of access points on your mobile phone but you cannot connect to it yet. Only if you configure a DHCP server to the access point interface (/etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network) the mobile phone will connect.

Comment: I followed instruction similar to yours and I sticll can not connect my android phones. In particular I did the part involving `DHCPServer=yes` . And still my android devices keep trying reconnecting.

Comment: More details: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107188/android-wont-connect-to-raspi-access-point